# Target elements within a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have defined a class named `active-td` and applied some styles to the elements within that class. But instead of changing only those elements, it changes the styles of elements on the entire page.

This is a simple form of code I have included:

First attempt

```
.active-td > a, p, span
{
    color: black;
}
```

Second attempt

```
.active-td a, p, span
{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *child combinator* (targets only the children of `.active-td`):

```
.active-td > a, 
.active-td > p,
.active-td > span
{
    color: black;
}
```

With *descendant combinator* (targets all descendants of `.active-td`):

```
.active-td  a, 
.active-td  p,
.active-td  span
{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: So I conclude that I have to define separately.

Comment: Yes. Once you use a comma, the browser is expecting a brand new selector and sees no association to the previous selector.